# Angular: apply function to html variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs, overlay

I would like to present an overlay to a button by means of the following code:

```
<div id="overlay" ng-if="vm.showOverlay">{{control}}</div>
<button ng-mouseover="vm.showOverlay = true" ng-mouseleave="vm.showOverlay = false" class="btn" ng-class="{classWhite: control.values.value1, classRed: control.values.value2, classOrange: control.values.value3}" ng-click="colorChange(control)"></button>
```

Yet, the control I receive from:

```
<td ng-repeat="control in general">
```

is a complex object on which I should apply function:

```
    $scope.stateFromControl=function(control){
        var values=control.values;
        var resultValue=(values.value1)?0:(values.value2)?1:2;
        return translateState(resultValue);

    }
```

to get the value to be displayed. Inserting the function in the {{}} slot does not work; how may I do it?

Answer (score 0):

I (temporarily) managed it by adding a variable state I manage at each change:

```
var newValue={
            id: i,
                name: impianto,
            state: translateState(oldStatus),
            values:{
                value1: oldStatus==0,
                        value2: oldStatus==1,
                        value3: oldStatus==2
            }
        }
```

to be used in this way:

```
<div id="overlay" ng-if="vm.showOverlay">{{control.state}}</div>
```

Rough, but working.